# What is class overloading in the OOP concept?

Tags: class, oop, overloading

In the OOP concept, I know Operator & Method overloading. But what is class overloading?

Have any one idea?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319802/java-class-overloading).